# Electric Field lines through Gaussian Surfaces

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

I had a doubt that in case of a cylinderical Gaussian surface possessing positive charge in its volume, will the electric field lines be perpendicular to the curved surface or the two plane circular surfaces of the cylinder ? How are we supposed to determine the above ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It depends on whether you are talking about an infinite cylinder, or a cylinder of finite length, and also the distribution of charge in the cylinder.  Point charge?  Uniformly distributed charge?  Line of charge?

Comment: Cylinder of finite length with uniform distribution

Comment: Consider a point on the cylinder but near the end.

Comment: I am not sure if i follow. Could you elaborate a bit please ?

Comment: Imagine using Coulomb's Law to find the direction of the electric field at a point near the end.

Comment: well, in the question i solved, the electric field lines were taken perpendicular to the circular surfaces and parallel to the curved surfaces such that electric flux through curved surface was zero.my question is how do we know what the direction of electric field lines will be ?